# Angular 7 aot prod build UIRouter forRoot issue

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-aot, aot

I am trying to build my angular 7 app for production using `--prod` setting.

`npm run ng build --configuration=production --base-href /app3/ --prod`

I resolved various errors but I couldn't resolve below error.

> ERROR in Error during template compile of 'MainModule'   Function
>   calls are not supported in decorators but 'UIRouterModule' was called.

In my module I have this code

```js
export const SHARED_STATES: Ng2StateDeclaration[] = states;

...

imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    UIRouterModule.forChild({ // <-- ERROR CAUSING IMPORT
        states: SHARED_STATES
    }),
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
],
```

I am using `"@uirouter/angular": "^4.0.0"`
I know the fact that AOT cannot handle the function calls but module author has to resolve it. From Github source code I realized that they added AOT support, but I am not sure how to use that. I wasted almost 2 days for this issue and I resorted to SO for help. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE (7/15/2019): I tried to create the scenario for stackblitz but it didn't make any difference, but locally I was able to reproduce the error with below tsconfig.json.

```js
{
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false,
    "strictMetadataEmit": false,
    "skipMetadataEmit": false,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

The setting `"skipTemplateCodegen": true` is making difference. Any idea why? Is there a recommended way to resolve this issue?

Comment: hmm forRoot or forChild code example vs title maybe prepare stackblitz example

Comment: @Xesenix I did a quick sample to reproduce the problem. https://ufile.io/egfx03nk. if you issue the `ng build --prod` command you will see the error.

Comment: You can also find source code here https://github.com/anilvangari2005/angular-aot-issue

Comment: Switch tsconfig.json
`
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false,
    "strictMetadataEmit": false,
    "skipMetadataEmit": false,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": false
  },
` it worked for me but not sure if thats the result you expect

Comment: @Xesenix actually I wasn't clear in my explanation, but I tried that already. I meant that "skipTemplateCodegen": true produces error but "skipTemplateCodegen": false do not produce error. The documentation for that setting isn't helpful. I am curious to know the reason behind it rather than trial and error. Thanks for help.